# How to become member of a Real-Time Group to circumvent the "sudo" command

Tags: linux, real-time

I have a script that starts 7 processes. These processes interact with one another by sending messages and accessing the same shared memory and etc. I need 4 of these processes to run under SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR. My issue is that I cannot set a scheduling policy or priority for these processes without running under sudo. For security reasons I am not allowed to use the sudo command to run these processes, so I was looking into Real-Time groups.

My question is this: Can anyone point me to articles, blogs, etc. that will give me further insight into Real-Time groups? I am not sure if editing the sudoers or limits.conf file will enable me to accomplish what I am setting out to do. I just want to become a member of some Real-Time group that will enable me to run these processes and assign scheduling priorities to these processes without having to use the "sudo" command and entering a password.

Here are some links to the documents I have been looking through to try and learn what to do:

https://jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html

https://medium.com/kernel-space/resource-limits-in-linux-limits-conf-83aa442913e9

https://docs.kernel.org/scheduler/sched-rt-group.html

Comment: So, the first link tells you exactly what to do. Did that not work? If you haven't tried it, why haven't you?

Comment: I'm sorry, but asking for external resources and learning materials [is off topic here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2642/22222), so I am closing this question. If you can edit it to instead ask about  your specific problem and how to achieve what you want, that would be welcome.